I cant generate a preview of my 3d model in gltf
Im simply trying to insert my model for preview but I'm not a developer and cant figure out why its not showing up.
Here is my html code;
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-extras.animation-mixer@3.4.0/dist/aframe-extras.animation-mixer.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <a-scene background="color: #ECECEC">
          <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
          <a-robot
            id="robot"
            position="-5 0.5 -3"       
            src="https://cdn.glitch.global/a268f0f6-f14a-489d-b3cb-558fda9ac16b/scene-can.gltf?v=1712935681643"
          ></a-robot>
          <a-plane
            position="0 0 -4"
            rotation="-90 0 0"
            width="4"
            height="4"
            color="red"
          ></a-plane>
        </a-scene>
      </body>
    </html>

Here are the assets uploaded.

I simply cant make my 3D model appear.
Can anyone help me set it up?

The element a-robot does not exist in A-Frame, unless you define it yourself. You may instead want to double-check the a-gltf-model documentation, check your JavaScript console for any errors and share them in the question, or further explain what issues you're seeing. Most models require lighting, which your current scene does not include.
Aside: If you just want to display a model without further customization, something like https://modelviewer.dev/ may be an easier approach.
